# Required file 'alink.dll' could not be found while building projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I got this error in everyproject I have when I try to build .Im using vs2013 and also vs2012 ,they all give this error and do not build any project.Anyone who had this error before? I tried to reinstall visual studios but didnt change.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Either your alink.dll is corrupted in the .net framework folders or the application manifest files are corrupted.

You can try building the application without creating the manifest file.

1. Open the project properties window
2. click Application Tab
3. locate the manifest dropdown
4. choose the option 'Create application without a manifest'

Save and Rebuild

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I tried reinstalling vs ,or framework but still got same error in every project.I also create a new web site and build but still got that error.I dont know what to do more :))

Answer (score -1):

Do check your .net framework. I got same error and i found that it was because other prog/software was suppressing the required .net framework version.

Comment: I had uninstalled and reinstalled framework and also visual studio but nothing changed so finally I format and install all windows and visual studio :)) Not a solution but I had to do this.